# SQLite convert single row to multiple rows

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

SQLite 
I want to convert single row value seperate by ',' to multiple rows

### Example :

### Single_Row

```
6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16
```

---

### Result must be :

### MultipleRows

```
6
7
8
9
10
12
13
14
15
16
```

I tried doing it with substr function but getting unexpected result

```
select 
 numbers.n,
substr(CbahiHSSpecialtyUnits.units,numbers.n,1) 
from
  numbers inner join CbahiHSSpecialtyUnits
  on  LENGTH(CbahiHSSpecialtyUnits.units)
     - LENGTH(REPLACE(CbahiHSSpecialtyUnits.units, ',', ''))>=numbers.n-1
  WHERE HsSubStandardID=22 and SpecialtyID=2 and  numbers.n>0
  order by numbers.n;
```

[image]

One good thing is I'm getting number of rows correct.. But the values that should be separated is wrong ..
Please note numbers table is I have created for indexing purpose, with the help of this post.
[SQL split values to multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows)

Comment: Looking at what you are trying to do, which seems a very good idea, it seems that you can contribute a valuable insight into database design to other users. I recommend to create a self-answered question like "Why change from CSV in columns to one-to-many relation design?". Assuming of course that is what you do/did. (No sarcasm intended. If you let me know you are almost guaranteed an upvote there.) You could even link here as "How I did it with the help of SQLite...".

Comment: Yes Yunnosh, I have posted the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a recursive `CTE`:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT SUBSTR(Units, 1, INSTR(Units || ',', ',') - 1) col,
         SUBSTR(Units, INSTR(Units || ',', ',') + 1) value
  FROM CbahiHSSpecialtyUnits
  WHERE HsSubStandardID=22 AND SpecialtyID = 2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SUBSTR(value, 1, INSTR(value || ',', ',') - 1),
         SUBSTR(value, INSTR(value || ',', ',') + 1)
  FROM cte
  WHERE LENGTH(value) > 0
)
SELECT col 
FROM cte
WHERE col + 0 > 0
```

Or, if you know the upper limit of the numbers is, say `20` and there are no duplicates among the numbers:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT 1 col UNION ALL SELECT col + 1 FROM cte WHERE col < 20)
SELECT c.col 
FROM cte c INNER JOIN CbahiHSSpecialtyUnits u
ON ',' || u.Units || ',' LIKE '%,' || c.col || ',%'
WHERE HsSubStandardID=22 AND SpecialtyID = 2
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=8fcaed41e6e7c084897406a44899f6ea).
Results:

| col |
| --- |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
| 10 |
| 11 |
| 12 |
| 13 |
| 14 |
| 15 |
| 16 |

Comment: @Yunnosch yes, I'm not used yet to the new table formatting.

Comment: Same with me. Actually, seeing the table now, I am not so sure about "pretty" anymore.... Not your fault.

Comment: I'll mark your solution as answered. However I have found the solution already. Mr. Yunnosh. But your solution is quite understandable. Thank you so much and for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution

http://www.samuelbosch.com/2018/02/split-into-rows-sqlite.html

```
WITH RECURSIVE split(predictorset_id, predictor_name, rest) AS (
  SELECT CbahiHSSpecialtyUnits.SpclUnitSerial, '', units || ',' FROM CbahiHSSpecialtyUnits WHERE HsSubStandardID=22 and SpecialtyID=2 
   UNION ALL
  SELECT predictorset_id, 
         substr(rest, 0, instr(rest, ',')),
         substr(rest, instr(rest, ',')+1)
    FROM split
   WHERE rest <> ''
```